# Configurando Vagrant para equipes pequenas

Tags: php, vagrant

Tenho uma pequena equipe de desenvolvedores **PHP** e quero configurar o ambiente de desenvolvimento deles usando **Vagrant**. No entanto, tenho algumas dúvidas.

- Como disponibilizo uma configuração do Vagrant para que os outros desenvolvedores possam baixar e iniciar uma VM com a mesma configuração?
- Normalmente o acesso SSH é liberado para o desenvolvedor? Nós usamos **PHP** e eu gostaria de deixar aberto ao desenvolvedor executar linhas de comando, como o Composer e o Artisan, do Laravel.
- Caso haja a necessidade de instalar algo que dê impacto na configuração do servidor, como eu atualizo isso no provisionamento do Vagrant, de uma forma que essa atualização ocorra também nas VMs dos outros desenvolvedores?

Enfim, se alguém já teve essa experiência de configurar um ambiente de desenvolvimento usando o Vagrant para uma pequena equipe de desenvolvedores de uma empresa, gostaria de saber como vocês fizeram. Procurei bastante na internet mas não achei nada específico para o meu caso, apenas ensinando a configurar o **Vagrant** em uma máquina local.

Comment: Ola Vinhas e bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Pode postar o que você já fez? Até que ponto chegou? Senão sua pergunta será muito ampla e provavelmente será fechada.

Comment: Eae Vinhas, da uma lida neste artigo. Precisei fazer o mesmo semana passada e foi muito bom para iniciantes no assunto como eu. [http://flaviosilveira.com/2012/vagrant-facil-e-util/](http://flaviosilveira.com/2012/vagrant-facil-e-util/)

Comment: Obrigado Premiere! Vou olhar com calma, estou me orientando por um outro artigo também muito bom: (http://friendsofvagrant.github.io/v1/docs/getting-started/index.html). Está um pouco desatualizado mas já da pra ter uma noção boa do funcionamento

Comment: Já que está utilizando Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Comment: @Caputo Eu precisei para este projeto para dar andamento a outro. No entanto, pretendo voltar a questão em breve :)

Answer (score 1):

- Ítem 1: imagino que você esteja utilizando um mecanismo de controle de versões, correto? Você pode colocar os arquivos de configuração dentro do repositório da sua aplicação. Sempre que algum membro do time clonar o repositório (ou atualizar) terá as configurações atualizadas para trabalhar.
- Ítem 2: o comando `vagrant ssh` permite que o usuário acesso a instância que está rodando via SSH tranquilamente.
- Ítem 3: se você alterar algum detalhe do provisionamento, você irá atualizar o arquivo de configuração que, de acordo com a minha resposta para o ítem 1, será atualizado no seu repositório. Quando os outros membros do time ligarem a máquina novamente a configuração será alterada e tudo será sincronizado.

O [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) pode te ajudar a configurar a máquina com uma GUI legal (caso encontre dificuldades em configurar as máquinas).